# Datepicker make current td active class and remove prev selected td class non active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to make a current selected datepicker td an active class and remove the active class of the previous selected td.

**markup:**

```
<input type="text" id="Dateis" />
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function ()
  {
    $("#Dateis").datepicker();

    $(this).hover
    (function ()
    {
        // add current td active class
         //remove old td active class
    }, 
    function ()
    {
          // add current td active class
         //remove old td active class
    });  
});
```

**Jsfiddle:**

[`Active Class`](http://jsfiddle.net/LuS4C/2/)

Comment: Default behavior is like that only. If you look at the code, "ui-state-active" has been added whenever you select. Why you want new one?

Comment: Suresh Ponnukalai i want when i hover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#Dateis").datepicker().hover(function () {
        $(this).closest('td').addClass('active');
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest('td').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

---

Or

```
$(function () {
    $("#Dateis").datepicker().on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){ 
        $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

[.addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

---

Update After OP's comment

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Pfg5n/)</kbd>

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".ui-state-default", function () {
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('ui-state-active');
});
```

---

Remove today's date highlight

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Pfg5n/2)</kbd>

```css
.ui-datepicker-today a.ui-state-highlight {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url(/themeroller/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: @user3400389 see --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/LuS4C/4/ you need to make table in html .

Comment: but this is not hovering on the td.

Comment: and please tell me how i do remove the already select td class. see the date 13.